# Which circular loop is having strong magnetic strength?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Which of the circular loopes will have stronger magnetic field having same current flowing through them?

A small radius loop or a Big radius loop? Or do they have same strength  (**both in centre as well as other than centre**)?

And if not , The **reason** for why the particular loop's field is stronger?

Comment: I assume you mean the magnitude at the center  of the loop. See equation (01) and Figure in my answer here [A generalization of the Biot-Savart law for a number  n  of wires with  n≥3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550087/a-generalization-of-the-biot-savart-law-for-a-number-n-of-wires-with-n-geq-3) to have an idea for an answer by yourself.

Comment: Related : [Similarity between magnetic field created by a straight wire and wire loop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387969/similarity-between-magnetic-field-created-by-a-straight-wire-and-wire-loop?rq=1).

Comment: @Frobenius, yes....but what about magnetic field other than centre?

Comment: Think, your last comment-question has no sense.

Comment: Actually....i am first time studying magnetic field and all, so my concelt abt magnetic field strength is not  clear, i mean in books it is written "the closer the magnetic field lines are  stronger the strength" but i didnt understand what actually 'magnetic strength' means here? Is the 'number of field lines' in a unit area or 'the actual strength of a single field  line'? I am having difficulty in explaining u my doubt hope you can understand my doubt . I will try to give you an analogy in order to explain my doubt. See ...lets say there are two places 'A' and 'B'

Comment: And in place A ,B i keep 2 cuboidal boxes at each place, and some bullets are firing in a horizontal line in both places, now in place A , 3 bullet hit the box at same time  on its front face make it slide, similarly in place B 5 bullets hit the front face of box in horizontal line at same time , makes the box to slide even farther than in case A. Now  consider those bullets as field lines and box as another magnetised object and the force by bullet as magnetic field strength. Now my doubt is " On what the magnetic strenth depends ? Its like all bullets have same speed in both cases but

Comment: In case B its **density** is more, hence nore force can be feel in case B by box OR the speed of a single bullet is itself high in case B that make box expirience more force" here wht i mean is that " does magnetic field strength depends on no. Of field lines(having same strength each)in an area  OR each field line having higher strength itself ??" I know its confusing but pls...try to understand my query sir. Its all new to me

Answer (score 1):

The field at the center is proportional to I/R, for radius R.
Off center, the smaller radius will still give the stronger field.